# Bootstrap 4 - .btn with data-toggle="collapse" while href anchor to an ID

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4, anchor-scroll

I've tried to anchor to an ID while also triggering a data-toggle collapse:

```
<a href="#id"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" class="btn btn-primary" title="Something cool">Something very cool</a>
```

for anchoring to this point

```
<div id="id" class="col-12 col-lg-6"><h4>A great heading</h4></div>
```

and collapsing this

```
<div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion"><p>A lot of cool stuff</p></div>
```

The collapse-part works, but the page doesn't scroll down to the anchor point. I can imagine that there is a problem with using two IDs. Is there an easy solution to make the feature work? Looking forward to your input.

Kind regards
Louis

Comment: can you provide snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `onclick="document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();"` to your opening `a` tag.

I'm not sure how good this solution is in terms of accessibility.